# PHP Dropbox integration with dynamic redirect uri

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on a PHP app in which I need to integrate Dropbox. Following is my code:

```
require_once ("../dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php");
use \Dropbox as dbx;
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("../dropbox-config.json");
$csrfTokenStore = new dbx\ArrayEntryStore($_SESSION, 'dropbox-auth-csrf-token');
$redirect_uri = "https://www.myapp.com/redirecturi.php";
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuth($appInfo, "MyApp", $redirect_uri, $csrfTokenStore);
$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
```

This is working fine with a static redirect uri. But in my app, redirect uri will be different for different sub domains, like, https://abc.myapp.com/redirecturi.php, https://xyz.myapp.com/redirecturi.php etc.

But Dropbox is not allowing dynamic redirect uris. Another solution is to use static redirect uri and send parameters from which I can create uri. But I dont know how to send parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a static redirect URI.

But when you call `start`, you can pass a parameter which will then be returned to you when you call `finish` after authorization. You could pass the information you need through there (e.g. the subdomain you want to send the user to).